# notifyDataSetChanged not working on when adapter change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I am getting data from server and then parsing it and storing it in a List. I am using this list for the RecyclerView's adapter. I am using Fragments.

I extended

```
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
```

this my complete adapter class

```
public class GridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GridAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<ProductModel> list;
    ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public GridAdapter(List<ProductModel> list, ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.list              = list;
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    public void update(int position,ProductModel pm){
        Log.v("update adapter",position+"");
        list.set(position,pm); 
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final ProductModel cp = list.get(position);

        holder.tvName.setText(cp.name);
        holder.tvPrice.setText(cp.price);
        holder.ratingBar.setRating(cp.rate);

        Log.v("grid",cp.id + "=="+ cp.checked);
        if(cp.checked==1){
            holder.imgCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            holder.imgCheck.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) holder.ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
        stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

        holder.lnrItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                itemClickListener.onItemClick(cp,position);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tvName, tvPrice;
        ImageView imgMenu, imgCheck;
        LinearLayout lnrItem;
        RatingBar ratingBar;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            lnrItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lnrItem);
            imgMenu = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgMenu);
            imgCheck = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgCheck);
            tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            ratingBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
            tvPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
        }
    }
}
```

and in fragment activity i use this code to load adapter to recyclerview

```
public void fillListProduct(List<ProductModel> mItems) { //method for load adapter for the first time
        mAdapterGrid = new GridAdapter(mItems,this);
        recGrid.setAdapter(mAdapterGrid);
    }

void update(){ //method to change checked value
mAdapterGrid.update(cp.row,cp);
                        mAdapterGrid.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

in my custom adapter i have 3 variable lets call **id, name, checked**, everything work properly, in first load i set **0** as default value for `checked`, in my scenario user can change `checked` value by tap the row of recycleview.

my question is, when user tap desire row then checked will change from 0 to 1 and display it to recycelview, i already use `notifydatasetchange()` but not working.

Please help.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove                        `mAdapterGrid.notifyDataSetChanged();`
 and modify this function in your adpater:

```
 public void update(int position,ProductModel pm){
        Log.v("update adapter",position+"");
        list.set(position,pm);
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
```

Comment: Did u check if the **list** of **ProductModel** is updated or no before calling         notifyItemChanged(position);
 ?